# PHP - PECL dll could not be found

Tags: php, dll, pecl

I'm having an issue that I cannot solve thanks to the different forums I've bee visiting.

I have a similar problem installing two different new DLL on my webserver : `php_imagick.dll` (ImageMagick) and `php_ssh2.dll` (to use SFTP).

My website is currently running on a `IIS 7 - 64 bits server` ; I've decided to install `PHP 5.5.14 VC11 NTS x86 (32 bits)` instead. Everything worked fine.

So today I downloaded my two new DLL (PHP5.5/NTS version for each one) and added it into the PHP extension dir. I checked that the folder was the right one by removing other DLL and I can clearly see it's the right one !).

By when I restart my webserver, I got the following error :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php55\ext\php_ssh2.dll' - The specified module could not be found in Unknown on line 0.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php55\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found in Unknown on line 0.
```

I've tried x64 DLL, I restarded the server, I can't work :(

Any idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with imagick. You have to download the latest version from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick. Make sure you click "DLL" under the downloads column. Once you download the zip file, copy all of the `CORE_RL_*.dll` libraries to your extension folder.

To get imagick working, I added the extension folder to my system path. See this link for instructions on appending the system path. http://www.howtogeek.com/118594

I don't know why this works, but it appears that the `php_imagick.dll` library is looking for the `CORE_RL_*.dll` libraries in the system path.

Answer (score 0):

OK I already have the answer for the `php_ssh2.dll` library.

The PHP5.5 SSH2 PECL extension misses the `libssh2.dll` library. You have to download the SSH2 for PHP5.4 which contains a libssh2.dll working good for PHP5.5 also.

Continuing to search for the solution for Imagick.